# .NET AWSSDK.SimpleEmailV2 - Friendly Name in From Address

Tags: .net, email, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-net

Has anyone gotten the SimpleEmailV2 SDK to correctly show a friendly name as a From address? I've tried to go with the standard that should be supported, but I'm not getting the display I expect in my email client.

```cs
var sendEmailRequest = new SendEmailRequest
{
    FromEmailAddress = "John Doe <no-reply@johndoe.com>", // i have an actual address here    
    Destination = new Destination
    {
        ToAddresses = new List<string> { "you@example.com" } // i have an actual address here
    },
    Content = new EmailContent
    {
        Simple = new Message
        {
            Subject = new Content { Data = "TEST Email subject" },
            Body = new Body 
            {
                IsHtml = false,
                Text = "This is the body of my email"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I expect to see  "John Doe" in my email client as the sender, but I see "Johndoe No-Reply". Is there a flag or property I'm not assigning correctly to get SES set to this properly?